# ModuleNotFoundError error when running sudo systemctl status gunicorn

Tags: server, vps

I'm trying to deploy a Django project on Ubuntu server.  I'm folwing this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04).

But I'm facing a problem when I run this command `sudo systemctl status gunicorn`, I get this error:

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-08-31 20:53:12 UTC; 6min ago
TriggeredBy: ● gunicorn.socket
    Process: 1918 ExecStart=/home/houssem/project/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock config.wsgi:application (code=exited, >
   Main PID: 1918 (code=exited, status=3)

Aug 31 20:53:12 ubuntu-20-lts gunicorn[1932]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Aug 31 20:53:12 ubuntu-20-lts gunicorn[1932]:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Aug 31 20:53:12 ubuntu-20-lts gunicorn[1932]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_extensions'
Aug 31 20:53:12 ubuntu-20-lts gunicorn[1932]: [2021-08-31 20:53:12 +0000] [1932] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 1932)
Aug 31 20:53:12 ubuntu-20-lts gunicorn[1918]: [2021-08-31 20:53:12 +0000] [1918] [WARNING] Worker with pid 1931 was terminated due to signal 15
Aug 31 20:53:12 ubuntu-20-lts gunicorn[1918]: [2021-08-31 20:53:12 +0000] [1918] [WARNING] Worker with pid 1932 was terminated due to signal 15
Aug 31 20:53:12 ubuntu-20-lts gunicorn[1918]: [2021-08-31 20:53:12 +0000] [1918] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Aug 31 20:53:12 ubuntu-20-lts gunicorn[1918]: [2021-08-31 20:53:12 +0000] [1918] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
Aug 31 20:53:12 ubuntu-20-lts systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
Aug 31 20:53:12 ubuntu-20-lts systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

When I run this command `gunicorn config.wsgi:application --preload -b 0.0.0.0:8000` it works fine and I can access the site using the IP address.

My `gunicorn.service` and `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket` files look like this:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/sammy/myprojectdir
ExecStart=/home/sammy/myprojectdir/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

All the mentioned (in the guide) commands related to gunicorn before this one `sudo systemctl status gunicorn` work as expected and print the same output as in the guide.

I searched for solutions but I can't figure out how to fix this issue, I'm new to gunicorn.

So please can anyone help me to fix this?

I can provide more detail if the provided information is not enough.

**EDIT**

About the packages, I've already installed the packages in the virtualenv from a requirements.txt file: `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Also, I've installed the django-extension globally but still have the same error.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44289643/importerror-no-module-named-django-extensions. I did not see anywhere in your link that mentioned installing `django-extensions`.

Comment: @ajgringo619 I've already installed all the needed packages in a virtualenv from the requirements file: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: @Community I add an edit to the question, please could you tell me which points should I highlight?

Comment: You may like to check on how I solved a similar situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70945714/8523960